# Kill oracle jobs in dba_jobs_running

Tags: oracle

I have scheduled jobs running that are not stopping even after restarting the server 50 times. i am a beginner in oracle. i tried to kill the job manually as below but still, after few seconds the jobs are back!. i tried everything with my little knowledge. please  somebody help me out on this

using oracle 11 g

1. Mark the DBMS_JOB as Broken
   2.Kill the Oracle Session
   3.Kill the O/S Process (unable to do it as i am using terminal service. But restarted server/PC several times)
2. Alter the Job Queue to Zero

have done everything .please help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the job submitted with some small interval. You can view all of them using

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS ;
```

In case you do not want any jobs to be executed, then disable their processes completely:

```
alter system set JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES=0;
```

Then restart your database. I hope it is not a production, otherwise please contact your DBA.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .the jobs are scheduled and i want them to be executed .I need the running jobs to be stopped. These jobs are synchronising  tables in server .due to these running jobs get failed next schedule is not running.

Comment: What would you like to do? To kill the jobs? To fix their logic?